# NHibernate IPreUpdateEventListener, IPreInsertEventListener not saving to DB

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, orm

I'm trying to implement simple auditing on my entities. Auditable entities implement the `ITimestampable` interface which defines `DateAdded` and `DateModified` properties.

I created and registered a event listener to populate these values. Here is the complete code.

```
internal class TimeStampEventListener : IPreUpdateEventListener, IPreInsertEventListener
    {
        public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Entity is ITimestampable)
            {
                (e.Entity as ITimestampable).DateModified = DateTime.Now;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Entity is ITimestampable)
            {
                (e.Entity as ITimestampable).DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void Register(Configuration configuration)
        {
            configuration.SetListener(ListenerType.PreInsert, this);
            configuration.SetListener(ListenerType.PreUpdate, this);
        }
    }
```

Now, when I make a session flush, the listener gets called, audit properties are correctly set, but most of the time they are not saved to the DB. By "most of the time" I mean that very rarely the values actually get persisted. I'm not sure, but it looks like on the first insert/update after the app is started, which is even more weird.

Of course, first I make a change to the entity, the change is persisted, but the audit property is not.

When I look at the generated SQL in the profiler I see that NULL is send in the query instead of the current time, so I'm guessing it is not a DB issues. Btw. I'm using MySQL and `DateAdded` and `DateModified` column are `DATE` type.

On the NHibernate site these properties are mapped only as `<property>`. Maybe I'm missing some "special" mapping for cases like these... ?

I'm completely stuck on this. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would be hidden/revealed in this cites from Ayende's article

- [NHibernate IPreUpdateEventListener & IPreInsertEventListener](http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener)

> ...Here comes the subtlety, however. We cannot just update the entity state. The reason for that is quite simple, **the entity state was extracted from the entity and place in the entity state, any change that we make to the entity state would not be reflected in the entity itself.** That may cause the database row and the entity instance to go out of sync, and make cause a whole bunch of really nasty problems that you wouldn’t know where to begin debugging.
>
> **You have to update both** the entity and **the entity state** in these two event listeners (this is not necessarily the case in other listeners, by the way). Here is a simple example of using these event listeners:

This is the code showing how to, from the same article:

```
public class AuditEventListener : IPreUpdateEventListener, IPreInsertEventListener
{
    public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent @event)
    {
        var audit = @event.Entity as IHaveAuditInformation;
        if (audit == null)
            return false;

        var time = DateTime.Now;
        var name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "UpdatedAt", time);
        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "UpdatedBy", name);

        audit.UpdatedAt = time;
        audit.UpdatedBy = name;

        return false;
    }

    public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent @event)
    {
        var audit = @event.Entity as IHaveAuditInformation;
        if (audit == null)
            return false;


        var time = DateTime.Now;
        var name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "CreatedAt", time);
        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "UpdatedAt", time);
        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "CreatedBy", name);
        Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "UpdatedBy", name);

        audit.CreatedAt = time;
        audit.CreatedBy = name;
        audit.UpdatedAt = time;
        audit.UpdatedBy = name;

        return false;
    }
```

And here is the magical `Set()`

```
private void Set(IEntityPersister persister, object[] state
       , string propertyName, object value)
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(persister.PropertyNames, propertyName);
    if (index == -1)
        return;
    state[index] = value;
}
```