# Is it possible for a NHibernate EventListener to modify the contents of a HasMany relationship?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, has-many

I am working with an application that has several domain objects with their own mapping to a similar list of `HasMany` domain objects. The application is running on-top of a brownfield database, so the structure cannot be easily changed. Each parent fluent mapping looks similar to:

```
HasMany(x => x.Locations)   // Location Type applicable to the given parent
    .AsBag()
    .KeyColumn("parent_sk")
    .LazyLoad()
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Every time a location on a parent domain object is changed the associated parent objects must have their location properties synchronized (some new locations added, some deleted, others left as is) within the same transaction.

I've created and registered an NHibernate Event Listener that implements IPreUpdateEventListener, IPreInsertEventListener, and IPreDeleteEventListener. This event listener fires as expected when a change is made to any Location domain objects.

Once fired the proper parents are found and their Location collections are manipulated in order to add/remove locations. Parents are then sent to the appropriate repository save method. I'd expect the changes to the locations collection to cascade. This however is not the case.

When debugging I've verified that the expected values are present in the collection, but nothing is modified in the database, nor is anything attempted as far as I can tell via SHOW_SQL logs. If in the process I modify a non-relationship property on the parent the changes are indeed persisted on the parent, yet the children remain unchanged.

Is there a proper way to configure a listener to modify children of a `HasMany` in a cascade?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that the answer could be found in this Q&A:

- [NHibernate IPreUpdateEventListener, IPreInsertEventListener not saving to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908367/)

that is in fact in the Ayende's article:

- [NHibernate IPreUpdateEventListener & IPreInsertEventListener](http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener)

> ...Here comes the subtlety, however. We cannot just update the entity state. The reason for that is quite simple, **the entity state was extracted from the entity and placed in the entity state, any change that we make to the entity state would not be reflected in the entity itself.** That may cause the database row and the entity instance to go out of sync, and make cause a whole bunch of really nasty problems that you wouldn’t know where to begin debugging.

And the description how to solve that issue:

> **You have to update both** the entity and **the entity state** in these two event listeners (this is not necessarily the case in other listeners, by the way)...

A small code snippet, which must be adjusted to the above needs *(handling collection elements)*

```
public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent @event)
{
    ...
    Set(@event.Persister, @event.State, "UpdatedAt", time);
...

// the way how to assure that even the State is updated
private void Set(IEntityPersister persister, object[] state
          , string propertyName, object value)
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(persister.PropertyNames, propertyName);
    if (index == -1)
        return;
    state[index] = value;
}
```

So, keeping both **entity** and **entity state** updated, would be the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem is the .Inverse() statement. That basically tells NHibernate that the location is responsible for the cascading and not the parent domain object... Removing the Inverse() would make the cascading work correctly.